# Touch event for sprite in cocos2d-android

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, cocos2d-android

In Order to make the sprite(canon) touch and react(firing bullet) to that touch in cocos2d-android, i have set `this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);` in constructor, and in ccToouchesBegan() added the below code

```
@Override
public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event)    
{  

    canon1 = CCSprite.sprite("android.png");
     canon1.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(10, 60));
     canon1.setScale(1f);
    addChild(canon1);

    CGRect canon1Rect = CGRect.make(canon1.getPosition().x - (canon1.getContentSize().width/2),
            canon1.getPosition().y - (canon1.getContentSize().height/2),
            canon1.getContentSize().width,
            canon1.getContentSize().height);

    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    CGPoint location = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(10,60));

return;
}
```

so when touched on sprite(cannon) bullets must fire out, but here the touch is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the sprite respond to the touch on it in cocos2d android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400522/how-to-make-the-sprite-respond-to-the-touch-on-it-in-cocos2d-android)

Answer (score 0):

*I hope this will help you.*

```
public boolean ccTouchesEnded(MotionEvent event) {
        CGPoint location = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(
                CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        if (CGRect.containsPoint((newGame1.getBoundingBox()), location)) {

            newGame();

        }

        return super.ccTouchesEnded(event);
    }
```